# Better control on code updates

Tags: version-control, code-reviews

I will briefly explain my situation.

I have a website in PHP, this website is powered by a custom framework + some "plug-in" made ad hoc for it.

I am the only developer of this. Until now I just test locally any changes than I upload the php files via FTP.

I don't feel confortable anymore with this. The code base has grown quite a lot and I need some sort of system that helps to keep track of changes (line by line) and can restore to an old version easly if something goes wrong.

Are there any good solution for this?

Note: I never used something like version control or subversion because I think they are too much for this situation (I am the only developer and I just need basic feature)

Note2: Something with a nice web interface would be perfect, I can pay for a good service too

As now I found:

- http://beanstalkapp.com/
- http://github.com/
- http://www.codespaces.com/
- http://codesion.com/
- https://bitbucket.org/

Comment: Do you have `ssh` access to the server, or just `ftp`? If you have access to a shell, then have a look what DVCS software is pre-installed, you may find that `git`, `hg` or `svn` are already installed. In which case, you could host your code on any code hosting site like [github](https://github.com/) or [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) but there are [lots of others](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2064945/42473).

Comment: @Mark: Yes i have ssh, I am on a dedicated server

Comment: Does it already have any VCS software installed on it then? Try running `git --version`, `hg --version` and `svn --version` for starters, that will tell you which, if any, are already installed.

Comment: No they aren't installed.. But I can install whatever I want. But still I need something that I can access from anywhere

Comment: If you question is about whether using version control is appropriate to your situation, then it is a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/895541/42473) but if it is a question about remote code hosting then it is a duplicate of [this question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/35962/22493). Please clarify what your question actually is.

Comment: Git + Github is probably your best bet. Industry standard version control, and what appears to be a decent online editor for quick remote edits.

Comment: Also worth noting for your particular situation: http://cloud9ide.com/. Should interact with git and github just fine. Also allows you to program from any web browser.

Comment: @Craige: thanks for your comment but I don't need to code in a browser, what I would like to have is a web interface to easly watch file differences over time

Comment: @yes123 - You said need "access from everywhere". I guess I assumed you meant access to the code from everywhere. Anyway, if that is not the case, I would just suggest Git + Github.

Answer (score 7):

Version control *will* give you what you want. It will show you code changes and file differences. It will let you revert files to earlier versions. Some version control systems will also let you automate deployment, so you can label/mark the files you want to go into the next build and deploy only the ones that you've selected. Some version control systems also integrate defect tracking and management, so you can look at the problem ticket *and* the code change to fix it all on the same screen.

You don't have to use all of the advanced features of a version control system but the basic ones will certainly do what you want. Any other tool that gives you these features is just a different form of a version control system.

If you wait until the project is SO big that you *do* need it, it will be more difficult to implement and integrate. Do it now (yes, I know there's a bit of a learning curve at first but it will be worth it in the long run) while it's still not too much trouble to add to your process. Another reason to learn version control is that many larger companies use it. Not having it on your resume, or saying "huh?" when someone asks in an interview about what version control system you use could hurt you if you're evenly matched against other applicants in all other areas.

Comment: Do I need to install this version control locally? Are there any solutions (paid too) that are Saas ?

Comment: "could hurt"? No sane, competent manager would hire a developer who's never used version control.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should stop worrying and start to love version control. That you are just one person working on the code is not really relevant, as you have noticed there are still a lot of occasions when being able to go back in time and review changes are very valuable.

These days distributed version control like mercurial and git are what most people seem to talk about. If you are just starting with doing version control I think howvere subversion is probably easier to get started with. The [svn book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) can be a good starting point.

Comment: I would like to use some Saas, I don't want to install something locally. Is GitHub the only alternative?

Comment: @yes123: no, there are lots of code hosting service out there. But why this fear of local installation? It's not a lot of work or likely to break anything. You don't even need to run a server, both SVN and git (probably others too) will happily work with a repository in a local filesystem.

Comment: I could see an argument for `svn` over `git` for someone who has no VCS experience, but I can see no reason to go with `svn` over `hg`. Mercurial has very similar commands for basic tasks, and is no more complex if you don't use the more advanced facilities, yet you still get all of the advantages of a DVCS, the biggest being the ability to work off-line.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt: I don't fear local installation, but with something hosted I could access it anywhere and I would take advantage of a nice web interface to keep tracks of changes or do other stuff (I believe...?)

Comment: @yes123: access from anywhere is a good reason to use a hosted service, but the IDE integration or GUI clients like TortoiseSVN and TortoiseGit are generally just as good or better than the web interfaces.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt: I mandatory need access from anywhere..

Comment: @yes123 - It sounds like you need a laptop then. In all reality, version control is THE standard way of tracking code, and the rest of the industry seems to manage just fine.